# How to trigger AFTER UPDATE in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm trying to run a procedure/function when a table gets updated (insert/delete/update), however, the function doesn't appear to get run when the trigger occurs or the trigger doesn't get triggered on an insert.

Function and Trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_rental_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
    CALL get_top_ten_rentals();
    RETURN NULL;
   END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_new_rentals
    AFTER UPDATE ON public.rental
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.fn_rental_trigger();
```

insert call:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.rental (rental_date, inventory_id, customer_id, return_date, staff_id, last_update)
VALUES (NOW(), 4030, 459, NOW() + interval '7 day', 1, NOW());
```

The stored procedure works as expected, and when I run it solo I get what I want. Running it from a trigger is failing with every way I attempt, so what's the correct way to run a trigger that executes a working procedure on a table update?

For context, this is based off of the dvd rental database from the postgres [tutorial website](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/).

---

### Edit

stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_top_ten_rentals()

AS
$$

-- Start a tansaction to get the data
BEGIN
    
    -- clear out existing data to refresh list
    DELETE FROM report.top_ten_rentals;

    INSERT INTO report.top_ten_rentals (title, inventory_id, rating, length, times_rented, total)
    SELECT f.title AS title,
           r.inventory_id AS inventory_id,
           f.rating,
           fn_transform_length(f.length),
           COUNT(*) AS times_rented,
           SUM(p.amount) AS total
    FROM public.payment AS p
        JOIN public.rental AS r ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
        JOIN public.inventory AS i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
        JOIN public.film AS f ON i.film_id = f.film_id
    GROUP BY r.inventory_id, f.title, f.rating, f.length
    ORDER BY total DESC
    LIMIT 10;

    -- Rollback when there is an exception to preserve data integrity
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
END;
$$

LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To answer Adrian Klaver's other questions:

- Yes, and that's intentional but open to change.
- Because it is a requirement, a silly one, but still required.

---

I have also attempted to run the trigger as so:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_new_rentals
    AFTER UPDATE ON public.rental
    FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE FUNCTION public.fn_rental_trigger();
```

In case running per row was needed, however, that also does not execute the procedure so the table I'm trying to update never receives any data.

Comment: 1) What is `get_top_ten_rentals()` doing? 2) What are the errors you get when you do the `INSERT`? 3) You know you are running this per statement vs per row?  4) Why not make `get_top_ten_rentals()` a  function so you can use it directly in the trigger? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver see edits to question, please

Comment: @CodeLee, man! Leave the weekends for resting and get back the following Monday! I'm pretty sure you are tired: the trigger is for *UPDATE*, and you are executing an *INSERT*!

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu does update not include C.R.U.D.? I was following an example that stated `UPDATE` encompassed multiple statements. Also, not tired, just new to PostgreSQL procedures as I typically use Entity Framework and/or SQLServer

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu, good catch.

Comment: No `CRUD` is `(C)CREATE(INSERT)`, `R)READ(SELECT)`, `(U)UPDATE(UPDATE)` and `(D)DELETE(DELETE)` where each is a separate operation.

Comment: @CoderLee, nope. CRUD stands for, not distinct, operations: CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE. When you define a trigger in Postgres (and almost all of the other DBMSs), you have to select which events the trigger shall respond to. Specifically for Postgres: `INSERT, UPDATE [OF colum_name [,...]], DELETE, TRUNCATE`. Here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu that was absolutely it, thank you! If either you or Adrian Klaver could post an example of triggering INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE in one trigger or however is more proper I'd be happy to accept that answer.

Comment: Heya! That's the catch :-) I don't know how to do it in Postgres. In SQL Server we have `updated`, `deleted`, and `inserted` (check the names, please) memory tables. Then, we have to left/inner join the target table with these memory tables and do the magic.

Comment: See here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html) Example 43.4. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Function for Auditing. It lays out the pattern you would need to follow.

Comment: Yes! `TG_OP`, `OLD.*`, and `NEW.*`. Bob's your uncle!

Comment: @MarcusViniciusPompeu: there's no `updated` pseudo table in SQL Server - only `inserted` and `deleted`. For an `UPDATE`, the `inserted` table contains the **new** values after the `UPDATE` operation, while `deleted` contains the values that existed *before* the `UPDATE`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fire your trigger for all data change events, code the *event* as `INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_new_rentals
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON public.rental
FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.fn_rental_trigger()
```

Since the top 10 data depends only on data in tables, and not the event (insert, update or delete) that caused the data to change, the trigger may be safely defined as one trigger for all data change events.

Comment: Except that is not going to work unless you make the function 'aware' of what operation is performed and what to do in each operation case. So this not an answer, but a comment. To make it an answer update it to include the necessary function mechanics to make the trigger actually work.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This works as-is. There is no more coding required anywhere. The trigger is just a wrapper for the procedure, which in turn just refreshes the top 10 list. The top 10 calculation does not depend on the kind of event - any change (insert, update or delete) to the rental table may affect the top 10 data and the refresh calculation is the same regardless.